# Immutables lib adds @Nullable to equals() method

Tags: java, findbugs, immutables-library

I have a very simple class and using Immutables library. The auto-generated code defines equals method like so:

```
  @Override
  public boolean equals(@Nullable Object another) {
```

The @Nullable annotation causes the following FindBugs error:

> NP_METHOD_PARAMETER_TIGHTENS_ANNOTATION: Method tightens nullness
>   annotation on parameter
>
> A method should always implement the contract of a method it
>   overrides. Thus, if a method takes a parameter that is marked as
>   @Nullable, you shouldn't override that method in a subclass with a
>   method where that parameter is @Nonnull. Doing so violates the
>   contract that the method should handle a null parameter.

I am using Immutables-value-2.5.6.jar

Has anyone seen this error?

I have mitigated the issue temporarily by adding:

```
@SuppressFBWarnings
```

to the Immutables class. But I don't think this is a long term solution. There must be something else I am missing.

Comment: Do you have a subclass of the generated code, perhaps, that overrides `equals` and doesn't add the annotation?

Comment: I would consider it ok if an overriding class broadens the input it accepts, as it happens in this case. Going from `@Nullable` to `@Nonnull` would definitely be a breach of contract, while going the other way is merely an extension of the contract. FB is wrong in this case.

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be an open bug in the FindBugs project (https://sourceforge.net/p/findbugs/bugs/1385/), so I would say that disabling the warning using an annotation is fine until the next release.

[This class](https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs/blob/master/spotbugs/src/main/java/edu/umd/cs/findbugs/detect/CheckRelaxingNullnessAnnotation.java) suggests that the SpotBugs project, which is the successor to FindBugs, have addressed the issue. Perhaps consider migrating?

---

**Update :** The FindBugs issue has since been closed.

Comment: It indeed seems FindBugs development is dead, and SpotBugs takes over.